# how to arrange div containers among each other without using float

Tags: html, css

i have the below structure on my website and there are alternating `float:left` and `float:right` assigned to these div containers. But now I want all these divs not to appear side by side (as they do right now) but one below the other

**html**

```
<div class="chat">
   <div class="chat-message a">...</div>
   <div class="chat-message b">...</div>
   <div class="chat-message a">...</div>
   <div class="chat-message b">...</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.chat{
    min-height: 100px;
    max-height: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative;
}

.chat-message{
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 20px 15px 0 15px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.a{
    float: left;
    background-color: #79d2a1;
}

.b{
    float: right;
    background-color: #7eaacd;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `clear: both;` to the `chat-message` class, as follows:

```css
.chat{
    min-height: 100px;
    max-height: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative;
}

.chat-message{
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 20px 15px 0 15px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    clear: both;
}

.a{
    float: left;
    background-color: #79d2a1;
}

.b{
    float: right;
    background-color: #7eaacd;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
   <div class="chat-message a">...</div>
   <div class="chat-message b">...</div>
   <div class="chat-message a">...</div>
   <div class="chat-message b">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you say : But now I want all these divs not to appear side by side
can you use bootstrap

```
<div class="col align-self-start"></div>

<div class="col align-self-end"></div>

<div class="col align-self-start"></div>

<div class="col align-self-end"></div>

<div class="col align-self-start"></div>

<div class="col align-self-end"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Flexbox

```
.chat{
        min-height: 100px;
        max-height: 600px;
        height: 600px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        position: relative;
        display:flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .chat-message{
        background-color: #D3D3D3;
        max-width: 90%;
        margin: 20px 15px 0 15px;
        border-radius: 8px;
    }

    .a{ 
        align-self: flex-start;
        background-color: #79d2a1;
    }

    .b{
        align-self: flex-end;
        background-color: #7eaacd;
    }
```